# What is the meaning of these numbers under the 'Prestige' medals?

Tags: jetpack-joyride

Under the 'Prestige' medals in Jetpack Joyride is a number accompanying the medal (#87 and #38 in the photo below). Do these numbers have a meaning, or are they just random?

[image: #87 and #38]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems they are just a way to number them. Here's a list of them from the [Touch Arcade forums](http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?t=106515):

- ID #001 Lonely Badge of Singularity
- ID #002 Double Badge of Rainbows
- ID #003 Sleepy Badge of Naps
- ID #004 Quadruple Badge of Bypass
- ID #005 Funky Badge of Jazz
- ID #006 Delicious Badge of Custard
- ID #007 Not so Lucky Badge
- ID #008 Prestigious Badge of Bacon
- ID #009 Sparkly Badge of Learning
- ID #010 New Badge of Double Digits
- ID #011 Annual Badge of Celebration
- ID #012 Dogs Badge of Walks
- ID #013 Super Lucky Badge
- ID #014 Adventurous Badge of Travel
- ID #015 Shiny Badge of Honor
- ID #016 Shiny Badge of Completion
- ID #017 Shiny Badge of Achievement
- ID #018 Momentous Badge of Age
- ID #019 Shiny Badge of Excellence
- ID #020 Shiny Badge of Courage
- ID #021 Tipsy Badge of Celebration
- ID #022 Shiny Badge of Persistence
- ID #023 Shiny Badge of Resilience
- ID #024 Shiny Badge of Skill
- ID #025 Shiny Badge of Accomplishment
- ID #026 Shiny Badge of Dexterity
- ID #027 Shiny Badge of Technique
- ID #028 Shiny bBadge of Prowess
- ID #029 Shiny Badge of Finesse
- ID #030 Shiny Badge of Aptitude
- ID #031 Shiny Badge of Talent
- ID #032 Shiny Badge of Sparkles
- ID #033 Shiny Badge of Greatness
- ID #034 Golden Frothing Badge
- ID #035 Shiny Badge of Deliciousness
- ID #036 Shiny Badge of Curiosity
- ID #037 Shiny Badge of Inspiration
- ID #038 Shiny Badge of Love
- ID #039 Shiny Badge of Creativity
- ID #040 Crisis Badge of Midlife
- ID #041 Shiny Badge of Brilliance
- ID #042 Badge of Meaning
- ID #043 Shiny Badge of Delight
- ID #044 Shiny Badge of Superiority
- ID #045 Great Badge of Honor
- ID #046 Great Badge of Completion
- ID #047 Great Badge of Achievement
- ID #048 Great Badge of Excellence
- ID #049 Great Badge of Courage
- ID #050 Great Badge of Persistence
- ID #051 Great Badge of Resilience
- ID #052 Great Badge of Skill
- ID #053 Great Badge of Accomplishment
- ID #054 Great Badge of Dexterity
- ID #055 Ominous Badge of Assassination
- ID #056 Great Badge of Technique
- ID #057 Great Badge of Prowess
- ID #058 Great Badge of Finesse
- ID #059 Great Badge of Aptitude
- ID #060 Great Badge of Talent
- ID #061 Great Badge of Sparkles
- ID #062 Great Badge of Greatness
- ID #063 Great Badge Of Deliciousness
- ID #064 Great Badge of Curiosity
- ID #065 Great Badge of Inspiration
- ID #066 Great Badge of Love
- ID #067 Great Badge of Creativity
- ID #068 Great Badge of Brilliance
- ID #069 Racy Badge of Controversy
- ID #070 Great Badge of Delight
- ID #071 Great Badge of Superiority
- ID #072 Special Badge of Honour
- ID #073 Special Badge of Completion
- ID #074 Special Badge of Achievement
- ID #075 Special Badge of Excellence
- ID #076 Special Badge of Courage
- ID #077 Special Badge of Persistence
- ID #078 Special Badge of Resilience
- ID #079 Special Badge of Skill
- ID #080 Special Badge of Accomplishment
- ID #081 Special Badge of Dexterity
- ID #082 Special Badge of Technique
- ID #083 Special Badge of Prowess
- ID #084 Best Badge of Birth
- ID #085 Special Badge of Finesse
- ID #086 Funny Green Badge
- ID #087 Special Badge of Aptitude
- ID #088 Special Badge of Talent
- ID #089 Special Badge of Sparkles
- ID #090 Special Badge of Greatness
- ID #091 Special Badge of Deliciousness
- ID #092 Special Badge of Curiosity
- ID #093 Special Badge of Inspiration
- ID #094 Special Badge of Love
- ID #095 Special Badge of Creativity
- ID #096 Special Badge of Brilliance
- ID #097 Special Badge of Delight
- ID #098 Special Badge of Superiority
- ID #099 Devastating Badge of Bradman
- ID #100 Badge of the Centurion
- ID #101 Shiny Badge of Spotted Dogs
- ID #102 Awesome Badge of Awesomeness
- ID #103 Heroic Badge of Heroes
- ID #104 Glorious Badge of Glory
- ID #105 Wonderful Badge of Wonder
- ID #106 Great Badge of Greatness
- ID #107 Amazing Badge of Amazement
- ID #108 Familiar Badge of Imagery
- ID #109 Brave Badge of Bravery
- ID #110 Lucky Badge of Luck
- ID #111 Prestigious Badge of Prestige
- ID #112 Honourable Badge of Honour
- ID #113 Warm Badge of Summer
- ID #114 Freezing Badge of Winter
- ID #115 Historic Badge of Fruit
- ID #116 Historic Badge of Sensei
- ID #117 Historic Badge of Raskullyness
- ID #118 Historic Badge of Zombies
- ID #119 Historic Badge of Echoes
- ID #120 Historic Badge of Racing Rockets
- ID #121 Historic Badge of Blasting Off
- ID #122 Woody's Badge of Programming
- ID #123 Sierra's Badge of Art
- ID #124 Muscat's Badge of Design
- ID #125 Last Badge of the Collection (?)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there are 125 badges. These are their ID numbers. I have 24 of them including 124 and 125.